# Suggest a text editor with template engine and code highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, text-editor

Can someone suggest a text editor with code highlighting and template engine, or maybe a plugin?
I need to edit long html files at my job, but there are a lot of templated actions like:

```
<p><span style="red">Text</span></p>
```

I need change to

```
<h1>Text</h1>
```

etc...and I want to automate them.

Comment: Well that would depend on what OS you are using and what you mean by HUGE? Perhaps a value in megabytes would help

Comment: mswindows, huge in meaning of "long". sorry for my bad english

Comment: Long like 1000 lines or 25000 lines or 20 Mb?

Comment: I don't know any text editors with templating engine. Regex yes.try notepad++
Template engine, I doubt it

Comment: u cud always use a programming language for your purpose. Python, php, even java will do the job just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, one of the best editors is NotePad++ but whether it can handle extremely large files is a question. If you are on Linux (eg: Ubuntu), you may try GEdit for ease of use with some plug-ins but to handle very large files, you're better off with Vim. However, Vim is not as easy to use in terms of keyboard short-cuts.

I often use GEdit on Ubuntu and Windows but for files that are large (eg: 20Mb) It is almost impossible to use this. Here's where Vim scores.

Finally, coming to the 'templating' issue. What you are looking for is a pattern matching and replace function. This is not something that most editors have but I do know that Vim has something down this line but learning to use regular expressions is something you'll need to do before trying such features.

Answer (score 1):

UltraEdit has always been there from the early days, and may be right up your street.